# File.ReadAllBytes() throw Exception

Tags: c#

I try to use **File.ReadAllBytes(FilePath)** but it throw Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException'

anybody can help me

Comment: Show your full work please.

Comment: How big is file you're trying to read?

Comment: the file may be more than 5GB

Comment: Do not read the file in one go. Read it in blocks (using FileStream.Read or similar) and process those as you go. If you need more specific advise, please tell us a bit more about what you want to *do* with the data in the file.

Comment: I have another problem with concat two byte[] on of them have more than 300,000,000 byte , it's make **Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown**

i  use  this code :

     byte[] b3 = by2.Concat(by1).ToArray();

Answer (score 0):

```
using (var fs = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)) 
{ 
   byte[] buffer = new byte[fs.Length];
   int bytesRead = fs.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
}
```

The above works well:

Comment: This will not work for a 5GB file.

Comment: yes it doesn't work for 5GB file !!

Comment: I think there will be no exact solution, as at some point of time, the system will eventually run out of memory. Another thing to do is read chunks of data using some interval so that memory can be claimed back

Comment: I have another problem with concat two byte[] on of them have more than 300,000,000 byte , it's make **Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown**

i  use  this code :

     byte[] b3 = by2.Concat(by1).ToArray();